# Jquery Ajax drop down issue on calling on focus method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello,

Currently I am unable to validate my text box which loads data through ajax call.

Find the code snippet below

JSP PAGE:

```
    <input type="text"  id="carrierName_ajax"  name="carrierName" class="field_size_e" onfocus="showRegion(this.value)" onBlur="checkValidCarrierName()"/>

    <input readonly class="field_size_d block" id="tier_ajax" type="text" name="carrierTier" onkeydown="return false;"/>

    <input readonly type="text" id="regionName_ajax" name="carrierRegion" class="field_size_e block" onkeydown="return false;"/>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $("input#carrierName_ajax").autocomplete("/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrier-suggestion", {
    }); 

    var carrname = document.getElementById('carrierName_ajax').value;
    if(carrname.indexOf("&") != -1){
    var res = carrname.replace("&","'||chr(38)||'");
    $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierId-suggestion&carrier='+res,{ "_": $.now() }, function(responseData) {
    $("#carrRefId").val(responseData);
    });
    }
    else
    {
    $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierId-suggestion&carrier='+carrname,{ "_": $.now() }, function(responseData) {
    $("#carrRefId").val(responseData);
    });
    }
    });

function showRegion(data){  
        /*Modified for Defect ID :219*/ 


    if((data!=null)&&(data!=""))
    {   

    if(data.indexOf("&") != -1){
    var res = data.replace("&","'||chr(38)||'");
    $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierRegion-suggestion&carrier='+res,{ "_": $.now() }, function(responseData) {
    $("#regionName_ajax").val($.trim(responseData));
    });
    $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierTier-suggestion&carrier='+res, { "_": $.now() },function(responseData) {
     $("#tier_ajax").val($.trim(responseData)); 
    });

    }
    else{
      $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierRegion-suggestion&carrier='+data,{ "_": $.now() }, function(responseData) {
         $("#regionName_ajax").val($.trim(responseData));
    });
    $.get('/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrierTier-suggestion&carrier='+data,{ "_": $.now() }, function(responseData) {
     $("#tier_ajax").val($.trim(responseData));
    });
    }   

    }   
  function checkValidCarrierName()
{
   // alert('here');
    var carrierName = $('#carrierName_ajax').val();
  // alert(carrierName);
    var carrRegion = document.getElementById('regionName_ajax').value;
    //alert(carrRegion);
    var carrTier = document.getElementById('tier_ajax').value;
    //alert(carrTier);

    if(carrierName==null || carrierName=="")
    {
          alert('Enter valid carrier name'); 
          document.getElementById('regionName_ajax').value = "";
          document.getElementById('tier_ajax').value = "";
          return false;

    }
    else
        {
        if ((carrRegion==null || carrRegion=="") || (carrTier==null || carrTier==""))
        {
           alert('Enter valid carrier name :'+carrierName); 
           return false;
        }
       else
        {
             return true;
        }

        }
```

Here my carrier name text box is loaded using autocomplete. Whenever a value is selected in carrier textbox it will populate region and tier text box.

Now the issue is if user enters any wrong value in carrier text box ie. 'only we' instead of weather.

I have to verify whether entered value is wrong. I am using onblur function validate. But it even checking when user enters first letter itself before selecting from the dropdown populated

Anybody can help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest not using onBlur to trigger your validation. 
I suspect because of the autocomplete the onBlur event is being triggered.

Another suggestion would be not using a alert for the error message, instead highlight the textbox or display the error message in the page itself. That way it won't disrupt users as they type. Doing this you may want to change the validation event to onKeyPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum number of letters required before jQuery searches in the list with 'minLength'. For example, refer to (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength). Note that you would have to set this option when you initialize the autocomplete ui. Just add 'minLength' option here.

```
$("input#carrierName_ajax").autocomplete("/maintenance/supportedCarrierSuggestions.jsp?command=supportedCarrier-suggestion", {});
```

EDIT:
To validate alphabets, you can use javascript Regular Expression:

```
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  //this is the pattern
if (carrierName.match(letters)) // check if only contains alphabets
   // yr code
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I cannot restrict user to enter the min character. If w is entered my autocomplete should populate all results starting from W which is expected. Could you please let me know how to restrict only alphabets are entered. But still will not resolve my issue

Comment: It seems like I've misread your question. What @Kristoffer said is appropriate. You may want to consider using other events than onBlur. Use console.log() for debugging over alert(). Let me know. :)

Comment: To restrict user input to only alphabets, you can use `pattern` attribute in `input` tag. Learn more here (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion for pattern but my application supports only IE7

Comment: Then you can only use javascript to validate that. please check my edit.

Comment: no problem :) pls upvote the answers or comments of other people that have helped you.